# Change CSS attributes of element

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, toggle

I have the following jQuery which toggles an accordion menu on clicking a button:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {  
 $('#chooseOption').click(function(){
  $('#accordion ul').toggle();
 });    
});
```

It works great!

Now, I was wondering if I can change both the **CSS** `height` and `background` elements on toggle too. So, when I click on `chooseOption` it will change the `height` and `background` of that element.

**Default CSS:**

```
#chooseOption {height:35px;background-image:url('1.jpg');}
```

**On Click it would change to:**

```
#chooseOption {height:55px;background-image:url('2.jpg');}
```

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer :-D

```
$(function() {  
   $('#chooseOption').click(function(){
     $('#accordion ul').toggle();
     $('#chooseOption').toggleClass("chooseOptionNew");
   });    
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a class for it and toggle the class:

```
$(function() {  
 $('#chooseOption').click(function(){
  $('#accordion ul').toggleClass("itsclass");
 });    
});
```

CSS:

```
.itsclass {
  height:55px;
  background-image:url('2.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a css classes as below

```
.chooseOptionNew {height:55px;background-image:url('2.jpg');}
```

use toggleClass(), This method will add/remove particular class,

```
$(function() {  
 $('#chooseOption').click(function(){
  $('#accordion ul').toggle().toggleClass("chooseOptionNew");
 });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) This doesn't seem to be adding the class. Here is my current HTML: `<h3 id="chooseOption"><a href="#">Choose an Option</a></h3>` - does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding or removing a CSS class to the menu with the jQuery `toggleClass()` function:

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the
>   set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the switch argument.

Usage:

```
$('#accordion ul').toggleClass('.cssclass');
```